# RestRessource not working anymore after changing Return Type from List to Response

Tags: java, rest, jersey, response

I have a simple Rest Example (taken from the Jersey Maven Archetype) with a RestRessource Category

```
@Path("category")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CategoryRessource {

    CategoryService service = new CategoryService();

    @GET
    public List<Category> getCategories() throws SQLException{      
        List<Category> categories = (ArrayList<Category>) service.getAllCategories();
        return categories;
    }
```

With this everything worked fine.
But now I wanted to change the Response Type to Response Like seen belown but if I access it this error appears:

```
09:30:04,688 SEVERE [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor] (default task-1) MessageBodyWriter
 not found for media type=text/html, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList.
```

The Ressource Class with Return Type Response:

```
@Path("category")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CategoryRessource {

    CategoryService service = new CategoryService();

    @GET
    public Response getCategories() throws SQLException{        
        List<Category> categories = (ArrayList<Category>) service.getAllCategories();
        return Response .status(Status.OK)
                        .entity(categories)
                        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .build();
    }
```

Here's also my Category Model Class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Category {
    private String name;

    public Category(){  
    }

    public String getName() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue related to MOXy (and it's use of JAXB). Type information is needed to serialize. When returning the actual generic type in the signature, the type is known. But when working with `Response` it is not known.

The general way this is handled in JAX-RS is to wrap the generic type in a [`GenericEntity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html). For example

```
ArrayList<Category> cats = new ArrayList<>();
cats.add(new Category("Cat 1"));
cats.add(new Category("Cat 2"));

GenericEntity<List<Category>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Category>>(cats){};
return Response.ok(entity).build();
```

Another option is to not use MOXy and just use Jackson. With Jackson, we don't run into this problem. It knows how to serialize by simply introspecting the properties. Just switch out the MOXy for

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>  <!-- not needed if you have 
                                                bom from archetype -->
</dependency>
```